# editing webhookRequest when using HTTPS endpoint (google assistant actions)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google

I'm using HTTPS endpoint as my fulfillment method and using my URL, it is making a POST call into my private server. But, I'd like to send in a couple of strings as part of the JSON payload. I'm not sure how to do that within Actions Console. My curl command would be:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'my_url' \
  -H 'accept: text/plain' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "title": "assistant_webhook",
  "summary": "webhook_post"
}'
```

Any ideas how I can add these strings within the webhook? After I run my project in the simulator, I see that the webhookRequest has these sections; handler, intent, scene, session, user, home & device. Which part would need to include the 2 strings?

Comment: What are you trying to return? Some kind of card, or text? What language are you using for your endpoint, as it seems like you should use language-specific HTTP libraries rather than trying to manage the data manually like that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I'm not even bothered about the response. As long as the POST can allow me to send a couple of strings, I'm ok with that. Right now, I've added a few custom intents and managing the "query" sent down as the unique identifier. The server is using C# (I think)

Comment: You're looking for the POST request from Google to include custom key-value fields?

Comment: Right, I am looking for a way to send a POST command to my private cloud server with some data. The "query" keyword is what I'm making use of now (as a back channel):      "intent": {
      "name": "POST",
      "params": {},
      "query": "webhook"
    },

Comment: That's not something that's possible. It might be better to dedicate a webhook exclusively to do Actions on Google.

Comment: But, if I change the webhook from" HTTPS Endpoint" (my current setup now) to "Inline Cloud Functions", there's not even an option to supply the URL to my private server. Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: "Inline Cloud Functions" means that the hosting will be done using Google Cloud Platform rather than your server.

Comment: Yep, that's why I've resorted to this workaround. Since I need just one unique identifier, the query field is working out just fine. Thanks for all the responses